# How to share login state through components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In vue.js I use `$vm.$root.user` to store user data and share user login state. In React.js there's context to share data conveniently.

But I did not find any document about it in React Native, what is the right way to do this in React Native?

Comment: I'd put it in a Service. In React for web and vue.js too.

Comment: What service? New to React and never heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

I use Reflux for this purpose (https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) both in React & React Native.

The way it works is you set up a store that has your logged in state, user data etc. Whenever something changes to those values (either through an ajax call, a user action etc.) you can fire an event from the store with an object as the argument. (The method name is 'trigger').

```
import Reflux from 'reflux'
import LoginActions from '../actions/LoginActions'

var LoginStore = Reflux.createStore({

isLoggedIn: false,
profile: {},

init: function() {
  // Do some initialization, e.g. checking if you've set some login information or tokens in local storage
},

listenables: [LoginActions],

loginUser: function(e) {
    // Do some call to a server to try and authenticate
    // fetch(...)
    if (fetch_result = true) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.trigger({type: "LOGIN_STATUS", loggedIn: true});
    }
},

logoutUser: function(e) {
 // ...
}
```

The LoginActions referenced above are a very simple module, for example:

```
import Reflux from 'reflux'
export default LoginActions = Reflux.createActions([
  'loginUser',
  'logoutUser',
 ]);
```

Your main application should listen to the store events, by adding a listener, and based on the object (that you define yourself) you can update states or execute some logic; e.g.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.login = LoginStore.listen(this.loginStoreListener.bind(this));
 }

componenWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the listener on unmounting
    this.login();
}

loginStoreListener(obj) {
    switch (obj.type) {
      case "LOGIN_STATUS":
        this.setState({loggedIn: obj.loggedIn})
        break;
      case "PROFILE":
        this.setState({profile: obj.profile})
        break;
    }
}
```

In your main application, based on the loggedIn state you can then decide which views to show, for example in combination with Navigator.

Comment: This is a rather odd way to use reflux. Generally you update the store's state and then trigger with the new state. It's bound to components with a mixin or [high-order-component](https://github.com/brigand/reflux-provides-store). If you're doing it this way, might as well just subscribe to the action in the component.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand it's true, I haven't explored the mixins, but this works well for me so far while I'm looking into using those. Could you expand upon your comment though? I'm not sure what the difference is between triggering with state or triggering with an object based on state. Since for both, you'll get an object in the listener..?

Comment: It makes sure that all components listening to a store get the same state. The point of flux is to have the state in the stores, not the components. The store is a place where actions are turned into state, and components just receive the current state of the store.